# Objects with application-wide scope in Swift Vapor

Tags: swift, object, scope, vapor

How can I create objects within a Vapor-Applicaton that are instantiated when the app starts and are acessible from within my controllers?

I would like to use `Dictionary` to store some of my models across multiple requests and assign them to a user via hidden fields.

Unfortunately `SessionData` only accepts Strings.

Many thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: Why would your application store objects of your models? Don't you use a database for that?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way is to extend `Application`. I used the documentation for Repositories as inspiration. First, create a structure to hold your properties:

```swift
struct AppConfig {
    var emailStatus: EmailStatus

    static var environment: AppConfig {
        return .init(emailStatus: .unknown)
    }
}
```

Then extend:

```swift
extension Application {
    struct AppConfigKey: StorageKey {
        typealias Value = AppConfig
    }

    var config: AppConfig {
        get {
            storage[AppConfigKey.self] ?? .environment
        }
        set {
            storage[AppConfigKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, initialise in `configure.swift`:

```swift
app.config.emailStatus = .unknown
```

I’ve used an enumeration as an example but it can be whatever you want.

Edit: Addressing OP's issues and concerns

1. I put the above code in a separate source file, so you need:

```swift
import Vapor
```

To gain access to `StorageKey`, etc.

2. Accessing the running application instance in a controller is easy, it's available from the request as in `request.application`.

Comment: Dear Nick, I tried to unravel your example, but I am missing a lot of things (StorageKey, storage, Value) so I am not shure what's going on.
Nevertheless I could compile it, using my dict instead of EmailStatus.
But I do not have access to the app-object from within my controller.
I tried to extend `Request` instead. That works, but of course, the req-object is not persistent. 
I think I will abandon vapor for my project. Alone, it is an effort to read the API, I cant find no index, no way to search for classes/structures/methods. Maybe i was too naive in my approach.

Comment: @michaD, Are you importing Vapor? StorageKey is defined in Vapor/Sources/Storage.swift. I fond Vapor quite difficult to begin with but it is worth the effort. I rarely fail to achieve what I set out to now, the framework is excellent.